# Issue connecting to SQL Server from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server

So my issue is that the program obviously isn't working, but it also isn't crashing. It's like it never executes the try or catch.

```
const express = require("express"),
app = express(),
sql = require("mssql"),
port = 5000 || process.env.PORT,
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
routerBoi = express.Router();

const sqlConfig = {
  user: "sa",
  password: "@Strongman105",
  server: "DESKTOP-RVS5F2QHSTESTSERVER",
  database: "master"
};

async () => {
  try {
    // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
    await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    const result = await sql.query(`select * from Users`);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

// console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The entirety of my output is "Listening on port 5000".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: where are you calling the code inside the try catch block?

Answer (score 1):

```
(async function() {
  try {
    await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    const result = await sql.query(`select * from Users`);
    console.log(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();
```

Just wrap your async function with round braces and make it self execution function. you can refer this in the official docs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait